# H2: Supplying an init script via full path (Windows 7)

Tags: c#, h2

Our C# application is accessing H2 Database (1.3.164) through H2Sharp. OS is Windows 7, 64bit.

The connection string

```
jdbc:h2:C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\TestAppStorage\TestDB;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\TestAppStorage\init.sql'
```

causes the following exception:

An error occurred while connecting to database:

```
IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\VS Projects\TestManagerApp\bin\Debug\UsersTestUserDesktopTestAppStorageinit.sql'."; "C:UsersTestUserDesktopTestAppStorageinit.sql"; SQL statement:
RUNSCRIPT FROM 'C:UsersTestUserDesktopTestAppStorageinit.sql' [90031-164]
```

The path value comes from user selections in the UI. How should one supply the init script with a full path under Windows? The examples I saw always use `~` as the beginning of the path but in our cases it may not be the case.

BTW, as far as I can see, the string is correct until the point it is handed to H2 from H2Sharp (i.e. H2Sharp is not causing a problem until the `java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, userName, password);` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use forward slashes everywhere:

```
jdbc:h2:C:/Users/TestUser/Desktop/TestAppStorage/TestDB;
  INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'C:/Users/TestUser/Desktop/TestAppStorage/init.sql'
```

The problem is that backward slashes within the [INIT part](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection) are escape characters, to support multiple statements as in the INIT part, as in:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=create schema if not exists test\;create schema if not exists data\;
```

An alternative is to double the backward slashes in the init part:

```
jdbc:h2:C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\TestAppStorage\TestDB;
  INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'C:\\Users\\TestUser\\Desktop\\TestAppStorage\\init.sql'
```

Comment: Thanks. I went with the forward slash method. I was confused at first because the backslash worked fine outside the init section.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with h2, nor jdbc. However it lookes like the backslashes get stripped. Try escaping them by adding an extra \: `C:\\Users\\TestUser\\Desktop\\TestAppStorage\\init.sql`

I believe this is because you are passing a string literal within a connection string, which needs to be (extra) escaped.